# configure xdebug for php 7.1.28

Tags: php, xdebug

I configure xdebug by flowing https://xdebug.org/wizard.php, and I'm pretty sure that I used the right phpize(/opt/lampp/bin/phpize-7.1.28), and after I compile, I put it in `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so`, here is the part of my `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` :

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
```

Then, I restart my apache server, when I check out phpinfo, there is still no xdebug.

BTW, is there any possible that my php version can not be configured with xdebug, because I noticed that the extension directory is `no-debug-non-zts-20160303`

Comment: Is the php xdebug module installed too? You can check `phpinfo()` or by running `php -m` and see if the `xdebug` is listed (is alphabetically sorted) in the output. If not, then install php-xdebug.

Comment: The question is that after I installed it, I still can't see it in phpinfo page

Comment: Did you also restart Apache?

Comment: I have figured it out, the reason I can't configure it right is I have another version of php， it disturbs my configuration of xdebug